# XDebug and .htaccess

Tags: apache, xdebug

Is there a way to activate xdebug for php debugging through .htaccess (Apache2)? For example by setting a value to something?

I know, that I can set XDEBUG_SESSION_START=session_name as parameter to a URL, but since I want to debug REST request, I would have to change it in the javascript code on different lines.
I can also add the autostart option to php.ini, but then it would start on all requests (not only on the REST-Server) and I would have to restart apache every time I want to dis/enable xdebug autostart.

Comment: http://xdebug.org/docs/remote lists some browser extensions that let you enable debugging by click on a button. And you can also enable debugging not only by URL parameter, but also via a cookie that you could set/delete yourself whenever necessary.

Comment: I know the extensions, but i can't set it per request :/